# Build variations of winforms application with different application icons

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a WinForms application that is used in several variants with different settings in the application's settings file.

Now I also want to build each variant of the application with a unique application icon.

Is there any way to accomplish this without having to go into *Project Settings > Application> Resources* and changing .ico file for 5 times every time I want to build the 5 variants of my application?

Answer (score 0):

Copy your proj file 5 times.  Change the icon in each proj.  Link all of your files to each proj.  5 proj files, one set of source code.  Rebuild solution and you will have 5 EXE's (as long as they build to different folders or have different EXE names).

Example of Linking

You have Project 1 with all your project items (forms, classes etc.).  You have a Project 2 with no project items. Right click Project 2, click Add Existing Item, find the form or class that you want to from Project 1 and instead of clicking the Add button in the dialog, there is a little arrow to the right of the Add button.  Click the arrow and click 'Add as Link'.

This will link the file from Project 1 so it is part of Project 2.  Both projects use the same file but it is only in actual Project 1 folder.

This may take a while depending on how many files you have per project but it is a great way to share common code and once setup, you only have to fix the code in one spot and all projects with the linked file get the update.

[image]

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I'm not sure I understand the "Link all of your files to each proj" part. How do I do that?